# Getting facebook extended permissions right from the start

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the following code which works when no facebook session exists

```
session_start();

# We require the library
require("/var/www/facebook.php");

# Creating the facebook object
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'app_id',
    'secret' => 'secret',
    'cookie' => true
));

# check if active session exists
$session = $facebook->getSession();

if(!empty($session)) {

    # Do some stuff here

} else {

    # There's no active session, go get one
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    header("Location: ".$login_url);

}
```

After logging into facebook, it goes to a facebook screen which says that my app will receive `Your basic info`.  Is it possible to get the email address right from the start too?  I know how to get further permissions after logging in successfully.  What I am after is to get extended permissions right from the start, most importantly the email.

What do I need to do to the `else` to get the email along with the basic info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell Facebook the scopes you need.

```
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email'));
```

Comment: And if you need more, just separate with commas 'scope' => 'email,user_likes,etc'

Comment: OP: read the [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) documentation - if you're struggling at this point, Jason's (correct) answer will probably only temporarily unstick you - you need a wider understanding of how this works, especially the [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) model